# given the following two conditions, find $f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose that a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $f(x+t,y)=f(x,y)+ty$;
2. $f(x,t+y)=f(x,y)+tx$;
3. $f(0,0)=k$;

then for all $x,y  \in\mathbb R$,  $f(x,y)=$

a) $k(x+y)$

b) $k-xy$

c) $k+xy$

I tried in the following way :

$$ f(x+t,y+t)=f(x,y+t)+t(y+t)=f(x,y)+tx+t(y+t)$$

so,

$$f(x+t,y+t)-f(x,y)=(x+t)(y+t)-xy$$

this implies $f(x,y)=k+xy$.

But could anyone solve this in a more methodical way, so that i can solve similar type of problems?

Comment: As you have been given the possible solutions, just check the cases, noting that you can eliminate $a)$ straight away as it doesn't satisfy $f(0,0) = k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you infer $f(x,y) = k + xy$?

I suggest:

1. Pick one choice and then see if it satisfies all the properties.
2. If it does, you are done. If it does not, go back to 1.

I think?

Comment: okay,. i understand. :)